# Qt5 странно поведение на Fedora 29

Tags: qt5, qml

Не понимаю с чем это связно. :

[image: Странные вещи на Федоре 29]

Такое начало происходить, после переключения на компилятор "Android для armeabi-v7a (Clang Qt 5.10.1 for Android armv7)". 
Обновлений вроде не было.Подумал, может проект как-то испортил, создал новый, все аналогично. Правда новый не смотря на множество ошибок, компилируется.

Comment: Не выкладывайте текст ошибок скриншотами. Отредактируйте сообщение и добавьте текст ошибок